# Using Default Locale Separator with NumberFormat, and then rounding number

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

I have this Java code:

```
  NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault());
  DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
  newCurr = df.format(dCurr);
```

Basically, I pass in a number, say 12.344.

I want it rounded two places AND to use the Locale's default separator (either "." or ",").  So, for example in some countries in Europe, I want this to be 12,34

So far with code above, I am halfway there. I get 12,344.  I can't find where to place the `DecimalFormat` of ("#.##") so it can be rounded.

In other words, I can I incorporate `DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.##");` in the above? or do I have to find another way?

Edit:  I am thinking I have to do the old way of (100.00 * var)/ 100.00 and pass that in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method setMaximumFractionDigit will do the work. See the rest of the available methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29

Comment: I think that with a combination of `setMinimumFractionDigits` will do what I need.  because I want whole numbers to end in .00 as well.  Edit:  it worked! marking correct